# how to map user login to another properties from Oracle OIM LDAP

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ldap

I have integrated SP 2010 with Oracle OIM LDAP. It works fine, but when the user is logged in the right upper corner there is number (number is a login in OID LDAP) instead of the user name. is there exists any way how to map this login from LDAP to username + surname or something another?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Oracle OIM LDAP but in general:

If you created [user profiles](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/about-user-profiles-HA001160317.aspx) for your accounts then user profile property `Name (internal name PreferedName)` is used for welcome control (right upper corner is default location). So you need to ensure that name is populated with desired data on [profile synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx).

If you are maybe not using profiles then loginname (in your case number) is used when rendering welcome control.